# How to resolve Azure Sql principal name formatted as guid@guid to a readable user name?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-azure-alerts

I'm looking some Azure SQL security alerts for a "login from a domain not seen in 60 days", however it's listed in the following format (not actual identifier)

f96bd1cf-beb7-4e82-89cc-3d7e76f1cf3c@1ed9389a-f140-4cfd-9f02-c5a6a78c2770

How would I resolve this to an actual readable username?

thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to share some snip or reference to the log attributes? it maybe UPN@UPN of the user or service that is now removed or deleted! see if this helps 
    https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39459757-azure-ad-sign-in-logs-record-the-userdisplayname-a

Comment: Was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try PowerShell commandlet to get ObjectId details, use `Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId` and `Get-AzureADUserCreatedObject -ObjectId` as below:

[image]

> In your case
> `f96bd1cf-beb7-4e82-89cc-3d7e76f1cf3c`@`1ed9389a-f140-4cfd-9f02-c5a6a78c2770`
> :  the first part is the `id` and second is `tenant`

Your Tenant ID should appear under Basic information.

[image]

Further `Get-AzureADUserCreatedObject` cmdlet gets objects created by a user in Azure Active Directory (AD)